# A class can't inherit from another one in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class named "OrderManagementSystem" and want another class to inherit from it, named "Order".

In the class "OrderManagementSystem" there is a constructor:

```
public OrderManagementSystem(string[] fl_cntnt, int scap)
```

when I made the class "Order" inherit from the class "OrderManagementSystem" as below:

```
public class Order : OrderManagementSystem
{
    public void O_print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

VSCode shows me a red line under the class name "Order", so I highlighted to know what I have to do, VSCode shows me that I have to create a constructor for the class "Order" as this:

```
public Order(string[] fl_cntnt, int scap) : base(fl_cntnt, scap)
{

}
```

why?

because I don't need the constructor in the class "Order" because the class OrderManagementSystem has one.

Comment: your object will still have to instantiate the base class which is why you need a constructor that has the params of the base class and you pass that to base(params),

Comment: This doesn't seem like a correct use of inheritance in the first place. Inheritance describes an "IS A" relationship, but _an Order is **not** an Order Management System;_ it's only _**one part**_ of an order management system.

Comment: You need an OverRide if you want a parameter less constructor.

Comment: my friends you mean that if the class OrderManagementSystem has no parameters, the class Order inherits from it and the code will work well isn't it?

Comment: @jdweng how can I OverRide ?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override#example

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need the constructor in the class "Order"

You do if an `Order` is an `OrderManagementSystem`, because constructing an instance of the latter requires those values.

Re-word your same assertion as a common analogy when describing inheritance and it comes out similar to:

> I need an engine in order to build a Car.  But I'm not building a Car, I'm building a Honda Civic.  Why do I still need an engine?

In order to construct an instance of the inheriting class, it needs to construct an instance of the base class.  So either the base class needs to change to have a constructor which the inheriting class can use, or the inheriting class needs to change to use a constructor provided by the base class.

---

**However**, this is a good time to take a step back and look at the bigger picture.  This doesn't make a lot of sense to me:

```
public class Order : OrderManagementSystem
```

Why is `Order` inheriting from `OrderManagementSystem` in the first place?  Is *every* "order" going to contain an entire system for *managing* orders?  An order is not an order management system.  A shirt is not a department store.  An apple is not a grocery store.

You can *resolve the error* by modifying the constructors so they align.  But I think that to *solve the problem* you shouldn't be using inheritance here in the first place.

Comment: you are right. I'll modify the constructor. thanks my friend

Answer (score -1):

You have to add a parameterless constructor on base class in case you don’t need initialize some properties, otherwise; you have to add all parameterized constructors on all derived classes.